# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model using execPopulate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have spent quite some time going over the multiple solutions presented for this error and i have tried them but none seem to work for my case.

i'm trying to populate a field with details from it's collection.

This is everything

2 collections

1. sups
2. surgetypes

Code for sups & surgetypes is in folders with the same names

Route declaration & mongodb connection is in host/app.js

host > app.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

mongoose.connect(process.env.LB_DB_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true, autoIndex: false })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Logbook DB attached to <<< ${process.env.PORT} >>>`)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Could not Attach DB because of::: \n \n ", err)
    })

//cors

app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors())


//middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(morgan('tiny'))


//SUB-APPS
const sups = require('../sups/app')
const surgetypes = require('../surgetypes/app')


app.use('/sups', sups);
app.use('/surgetypes', surgetypes)

module.exports = app;
```

sups > app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const supRoutes = require('./routes/index')

const app = express()


app.use("/", supRoutes)

module.exports = app
```

sups > models > index.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const supSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Jene: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    typeOfSurge: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'surgeType',
        required: true
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('sups', supSchema)
```

sups > routes > index.js

```
const { surgeType } = require('../../surgetypes/models/index')
const visor = require('../models/index')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const sup = await (await visor.findById(req.params.id).populate('typeOfSurge')).execPopulate()

    res.status(200).json(sup)

})


module.exports = router
```

surgetypes > models > index.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const surgeTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    specialName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

})

exports.surgeType = mongoose.model('surgetypes', surgeTypeSchema)
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to to populate the details of a surgetypes collection document in the sups collection document when sending a >>> Get '/:id' <<< request

A surgetypes collection document is already referenced by it's id.

The error is

```
(node:4608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "surgeType".
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i'm laughing so hard right now.

So, the problem is

this line

```
    typeOfSurge: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'surgeType',
        required: true
    }
```

the `ref: 'surgeType'`

should be `ref:'surgetypes'`

referencing the collection name

Oh the amount of hours i've dedicated to this.

The joy of programming Amirite?

Must be nice being an AI that programs with tried and tested rules.

Anyway, that was it.